# Min. weighted average distance from multiple points

Tags: mapping, geography

I am a complete beginner in mapping-related topics. Still, I´ve been wondering if anyone know this problem. It might be well known, I just don´t know its name.

Initial situation:

nx : x geographical locations

Wx: weight per location

Dx: distance between the location nx and the optimal location O

Problem:

Where is the geographical position O, where the Σ (Dx*Wx) is at a minimum?

Numerical example:

n1: Rheinfelden; Wx: 20%

n2: Zurich; Wx: 40%

n3: Berne; Wx: 30%

n4: Lucerne; Wx: 10%

Result: somewhere around Aarau in Switzerland

Does anyone know the common name for this spatial problem?

I have found a tool that can do this on a straight line ("as the bird flies", http://www.geomidpoint.com/) but I would like to be able to calculate this on a street routing level. Is anyone aware of such a tool?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you problem has a name ([the similar problem has one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median)) but you find this problem if one needs to know a meeting point of several people. And e.g. the higher percentage means more people at this point.

I would solve this with GraphHopper running multiple Dijkstras and starting at the specified locations and when all search areas overlap you have found the meeting point regarding the real path (the exact finish condition could be tricky though). Where you can even use different vehicles for every Dijkstra like foot or car.

Answer (score 1):

"As the bird flies" what you are looking for is called "weighted geometric median", see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_population
QUOTE
Geometric median[edit]
The geometric median is the point to which the population has the smallest possible sum of distances (or equivalently, the smallest average distance). Because of this property, it is also known as the point of minimum aggregate travel. Unfortunately, there is no direct closed-form expression for the geometric median; it is typically computed using iterative methods.
UNQUOTE
Also:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median

If you want to constrain your result to a graph, you could use Dijkstra's algorithm to route from every node in the graph to each location and sum by weights for each node (this would only work for relatively simple graphs, but there might be some short-cuts, like starting with the node closet to the geometric median and chasing the adjacent nodes minimums through the graph to identify local node minimums). From the minimum node result, calculate the equation for the results along the length of the arcs from the minimum node, and identify the minimum positions for each arc.
The question remains, is it possible that a minimum exists between a pair of adjacent nodes that do not include the minimum node? I think that this would generally not the case, but there would probably be pathological cases (like symmetric graphs), and it might be difficult to prove.

Comment: My comment applies to @Karussell's answer too. I looked at something similar with MapPoint and came to the conclusion that it wasn't very practical. This was partly due to my application, and also the "closed box" nature of MapPoint's routing algorithm. For a more general (one centre, one group of points), access to the road network/Dijkstra; it may well be practical for smaller road networks. I would expect the entire German road network (say) to take a long time...